# 302 Error when trying to access governance registry from developer studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I have governance registry 4.1.1 running fine.  when I try to attach to it from developer studio version 2.1.0 I can't browse the registry and the error below is in http_access log.

```
[17/Oct/2012:08:12:16 -0600] "GET //carbon HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Java/1.6.0_34"
```

Any ideas appreciated

UPDATE

Steps:  enter eclipse , go to , WSO2 registry work space, create connection to registry, enter credentials and get "Specific Remote Server is not running" .  Verified server IS running.  Appears to be a cert. issue but I am having no cert problems logging into console of GREG.  log entry below.

> !ENTRY org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base 4 0 2012-11-26
>   08:25:47.615 !MESSAGE javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target !STACK 0
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.execute(AbderaClient.java:805)
>     at
>   org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.get(AbderaClient.java:235)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.app.RemoteRegistry.get(RemoteRegistry.java:160)
>     at
>   org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base.core.Registry.getResourcesPerCollection(Registry.java:350)
>     at
>   org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base.model.RegistryResourceNode.getResourceType(RegistryResourceNode.java:258)
>     at
>   org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.base.ui.controls.RegistryTreeContentProvider.hasChildren(RegistryTreeContentProvider.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.isExpandable(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.isExpandable(TreeViewer.java:588)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.isExpandable(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.optionallyPruneChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.updateChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2608)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1923)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(TreeViewer.java:721)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1930)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(TreeViewer.java:721)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1930)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(TreeViewer.java:721)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1930)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(TreeViewer.java:721)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1898)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1855)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$8.run(StructuredViewer.java:1535)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:403)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.refresh(ColumnViewer.java:548)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1490)
>     at
>   org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.greg.manager.remote.views.RegistryBrowserView$51.run(RegistryBrowserView.java:2584)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.flushRequestOutputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1565)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.abdera.protocol.client.AbderaClient.execute(AbderaClient.java:791)
>     ... 53 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 72 more Caused by:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
>     ... 78 more

Comment: Please provide the steps to reproduce the error and would be helpful if you can post the content in Eclipse Error log file at /.metadata/.log file location.

Comment: Enter registry workspace in Eclipse

Comment: This appears to be a HTTPS connectivity issue due to mismatching SSL Certificates in Server and Developer Studio.

Have you replaced default wso2 carbon certificate with a custom SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes, I have.  It is working fine accessing it from other means.

Comment: Ok. That is the reason for this issue. Currently Developer Studio does not have a mechanism for user to input their custom SSL certificates. But it will be fixed with in next release cycles.

Answer (score 1):

This limitation is now fixed in the latest version of the Developer Studio (3.2.0) version by introducing a configurable SSL Client Store via Preferences for Developer Studio.

In order to set the custom SSL Trust Store,

1. Window -> Preferences -> Developer Studio
2. Expand the Developer Studio Preference.
3. Select "SSL Client Trust Store" and point to your SSL client Trust Store. (You need to provide a SSL Client Trust Store in your local machine here. Remote Addresses will not work)

Then Apply  and Ok.

Now you can try the same set of steps you followed and successfully connect to the Server with updated Certificates.

/Harshana